# pyspark worker log to file or console

Tags: logging, pyspark

any one knows how to log from a pyspark worker to either console or file? I set

logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/pyspark.log', level=logging.INFO)

but it has no effect. no such file is created, and no message showed up in console.

Comment: What is execution mode of your spark context? (local/standalone cluster/yarn). How do you configure logging on workers? Where do you put the `logging.basicConfig`?

Comment: well, I like to have this work for all configurations. But right now I am developing on a Mac and running in local mode. The config is declared right in the python class where the log statements are. The class method is called inside RDD.

Comment: Your configuration seems right. Please add some job code to the question (especially the class you call inside RDD and messages logging itself)